# Google Maps Error: Object function (){return this.get(a)} has no method 'contains'

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to execute the following statement:

```
nowMap.getBounds.contains(mymarker.getPosition())
```

but it is returning the following error:

```
Object function (){return this.get(a)} has no method 'contains'
```

The `getBounds.contains` call executes within a `bounds_changed` event handler to ensure that the `map` is ready. I read that this may be due to a bug in the `v3.14 api` so I upgraded to `3.15` and am still getting the error. Note that I do NOT get the error if the `jquery-mobile page` that includes the `map` is the first `page` I navigate to.

Comment: `nowMap.getBounds().containers` maybe?

Comment: I don't believe that is a function

Comment: Why not? The error message is telling you it is. Did you try to invoke it? And if so, did it tell you it wasn't a function?

Comment: I googled it, it's a function. `.getBounds().contains` typo in `.contains`.

Comment: TypeError: Object function (){return this.get(a)} has no method 'containers'

Comment: Why did you change to `containers` instead of `contains`?

Comment: I was implementing the solution that @Omar suggested in his first comment; that's why I said that is not a function

Comment: That was a typo, my bad. I typed the word _container_ too many times today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
nowMap.getBounds.contains(mymarker.getPosition())
```

There is `()` missing after `getBounds`. That line should be:

```
nowMap.getBounds().contains(mymarker.getPosition())
```